# convert date time to month/yearin oracle query in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, oracle

data will be read from excel sheet & store data table& i will insert data in database(oracle).but term column in database accept 7 bytes like mm/yyyy . but my input read data will be date time format.how can i do date time to mm/yyyy
below is oracle insert query

```
 strQuery &= "'" + String.Format("{%M/%y}", dt1.Rows(row)("TERM")) + "',"
```

Comment: any one can help i am strucking for last 3 hours

Comment: Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

When you read the date/time from excel, assign the value to datetime variable and then you can pull the month and year from.